# Unable to route to second edit resource Laravel-4

Tags: php, laravel-4, controller

I have a resource controller for member data. All of the usual resource functions, including edit, are working perfectly. I am trying to add additional edit functions within this controller so that I can create views that only are for specific subsets of the Member model data, since the data set is rather large. So, I've set up the extra routes and functions. But when I attempt to link to the edit2 resource, Laravel will not create the proper link. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Code:

Route:

```
Route::get('members.edit2', array('as'=>'edit2', 'uses'=> 'MembersController@edit2'));
Route::resource('members','MembersController');
```

MembersController:

```
// Regular edit function -- works just fine:
    public function edit($id)
{
    $member = $this->member->find($id);
    return View::make('members.edit', array(
        'member'=>$member, ...
    ));
}

// Extra edit2 function -- should work if I could successfully route to it:
    public function edit2($id)
{
    $member = $this->member->find($id);
    return View::make('members.edit2', array(
        'member'=>$member, ...
    ));
}
```

show.blade.php:

```
// normal edit link (works fine, see source code below):
<a href="{{ URL::route('members.edit',$member->id) }}">edit</a>

// additional edit2 link (creates a bad link, see source code below):
<a href="{{ URL::route('edit2',$member->id) }}">edit</a>
```

source code:

```
// normal link that uses edit for member id=27:
<a href="https://zocios.com/members/27/edit">edit</a>

// link that attempts to use edit2 for same member:
<a href="https://zocios.com/members.edit2?27">edit</a>
```

I'm sure there is a way of doing this. It doesn't matter whether I use the named route 'edit2' rather than 'members.edit2', the exact same bad link is created. I've tried every combination I can think of. Laravel docs are not at all helpful for this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your don't declare your `edit2` route as you should do. Your first mistake is that the member's `id` you want to edit is not passed as a parameter and the second one that by calling this `{{route('edit2')}}` Laravel expects a url like `/members.edit2` which is never going to appear. You should better use sth like `/members/{id}/edit2`. 
Try using this:

```
Route::get('members/{id}/edit2', array('as'=>'edit2', 'uses'=> 'MembersController@edit2'));
```

and call it like:

```
{{ route('edit2', [$id]) }}
```

Also be careful, whenever you call `Url::route()` or simply `route()` you should pass their parameters in an array like:

```
{{route('myRoute', ['par1', 'par2', 'par3', ...]}}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That all makes perfect sense, and it's working exactly as it should now. I'm still relatively new to Laravel, but it's all starting to click -- not as fast as I'd like, but I'm getting there! I really appreciate your help and your very clear explanations. Have a great day!

Comment: Thanks, keep on trying it will pay off your efforts for sure.